# How to add a new attribute to core wp block editor without npm?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I need to add a new attribute with color selector to a core paragraph/heading block. What would be `braces-color="#5a6a81"` for example. I've been googling all day and only found examples with npm installation. But I can't install it on wp hosting.

I saw the article https://jeffreycarandang.com/extending-gutenberg-core-blocks-with-custom-attributes-and-controls/ but it doesn't help without the npm.

Comment: what's the purpose of the new attribute? There are other and better ways to do these things such as block styles, variations, etc etc. The article you linked to makes no mention of `npm`, and it's assumed that you would be doing this locally on a local copy of your site, not live in production on a web host . Note that the examples in that article are impossible to use without some sort of build step, which is unavoidable, but you would never install `npm` on wp hosting.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for your reply. Some headings blocks must contain curly braces, such as `{Example Title}`. Because of this I want to add a switcher or button to the core block paragraph and heading that would add a class to the element. And also, an attribute with color for these braces.

Comment: you can do that by adding a class in the advanced section, or if you want to automate that in a clickable UI with previews/names/descriptions, block styles and block variants are how you do that. Adding brand new block attributes is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need block attributes to do that! Core has an alternative that provides a superior experience, **block variants**.

Block variants let you reuse an existing block, but declare a variant which has predefined block attributes that match your use case.

For example, all embeds are variants of the embed block, even though they have different names titles icons and descriptions.

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/

For example with this:

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation( 'core/heading', {
    name: 'bracketed-heading',
    title: 'Bracketed Heading',
    attributes: { className: 'heading-with-brackets' },
} );
```

I got this:

[image]

I can add new descriptions, titles, icons, previews, and HTML classes to style the heading differently ( with brackets ). No PHP needed.

The only difference between this and a normal heading, what makes it a bracketed heading is this:

[image]

Comment: Got it, I think that's the most useful solution. Thank you.

Comment: there is also something called block styles, which could be used for this, but variants is the more flexible option

Comment: Actually, as Tom commented, block styles are better use-case for this, because that is what they do - add certain class to block. Block variants are overkill, they are used when you have to set attributes values to certain pre-determined set.

Comment: block styles put a UI in the sidebar but aren't accessible from the inserter, and don't have customisable icons/previews/etc. You also can only have 1 style at a time whereas with a variant you could have styles on your variant

Comment: Can I change the default settings of these variations? Such as color, font size, etc.
I added a variation of the core/buttons. But for some reason the color and radius of the buttons do not change. Only the class works. What am I doing wrong?
`innerBlocks: [
  ['core/button'],
  ['core/button', {className: "is-style-outline", textColor: "blue",border: {radius: "0px"},},],]`

Comment: Also, how I can add block style to block variation?

Comment: yes, you define the attributes you want when you register the variant, but not inner blocks those aren't attributes, those are blocks/content. If you want to do things like that  involving multiple blocks then what you actually need is a block pattern

Comment: @TomJNowell, how can I `import { useDispatch, useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';` without npm? I'm unable to find any details for it?

Comment: @Motivated new questions should be asked using the new question button! This answer and its comments are for the original question, especially since my answer does not mention `import` statements `useDispatch` or` `useSelect`